# FUBAR after update to GAE-java-sdk-1.6.0/1.6.1 persistencemanager singleton

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo, gae-eclipse-plugin

After I updated from GAE-JAVA-SDK-1.5.5 to 1.6.0 and 1.6.1 my app stop functioning properly. it started giving an error on the RPC service.

```
Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract void com.skip.school.client.service.AdminService.addStudent(com.skip.school.shared.Student)' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.skip.school.server.PmfSingleton

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.skip.school.server.PmfSingleton
```

The whole log can be found here [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/EJTvQYrb).

I have a singleton that should be initialized when the user starts there first rpc call. 
The singleton I use should be correct there are many example found here on stackeroverflow and everywhere on the web.

```
public final class PmfSingleton {
    private final static PersistenceManagerFactory pmfInstance = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("transactions-optional");

    private PmfSingleton() { }

    public static PersistenceManagerFactory get() {
    return pmfInstance;    
    }
}
```

I call that class in all my server implementations like so.

```
PersistenceManager pm = PmfSingleton.get().getPersistenceManager();
```

this works on sdk 1.5.5 and below but not on sdk 1.6.0 and above, does anyone know what I' doing wrong what i should change if i want to use sdk 1.6.0 and above?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.appengine.api.datastore.TransactionOptions$Builder.withXG(Z)Lcom/google/appengine/api/datastore/TransactionOptions;

Comment: okay what does that mean? does that mean that the option transactions-optional in getPersistencManagerFactory is not the right way of doing it anymore?

Comment: It means some GAE internal API seems different (not JDO, but their JDO plugin calls down to it); needs comment from some Google person.

Comment: reported this issue to google. http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6625

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same problem after upgrading to a newer version of AppEngine SDK. It turns out the problem was I had an older version of the appengine-api-1.0-sdk jar hanging around in the deployment folder.

Have a look in the `war\WEB-INF\lib` folder of your application and see if there are two different versions of `appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.x.y.jar`. I fixed it by removing the `appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.5.x` file.

Answer (score 1):

I read somewhere else that this problem is related to an out dated version of the datanucelus jars. I've updated to the latest version, v1.6.1 available from the eclipse plugin and I fixed it by deleting all old references to the old jars, leaving behind just these 3:

- datanucleus-appengine-1.0.10.final.jar
- datanucleus-core-1.1.5.jar
- datanucleus-jpa-1.1.5.jar

I hope that works for you!